# Есть ли способ передать массив, как список аргументов, в функцию?

Tags: php

Есть вот такая пользовательская функция:

```
function subarr_cout () {
    $s = 0;
    $al = func_num_args();
    $vl = count(func_get_args(0));
    for ($a = 1; $a < $al; $a++) {
        $il = count(func_get_args($a));
        for ($i = 0; $i < $il; $i++) {
            for ($v = 0; $v < $vl; $v++) {
                if (func_get_args($a)[$i] == func_get_args(0)[$v]) $s++;
             }
        }
    }
    return $s;
}
```

Она получает, в качестве аргументов, некоторое число массивов, первый из которых содержит данные для сравнения, а второй и последующие проверяются на наличие в них совпадений.

Есть игровое поле 10x10 клеток, данные о котором хранятся в соответствующем двухмерном массиве. Мне требуется посчитать, сколько клеток определённого типа есть на всём поле.

Функция предполагалась как универсальная, для подсчёта количества совпадений в любом массиве, и переписывать её для проверки массива двухмерного мне не очень хочется.

Очевидное решение состоит в том, что бы переписать функцию для получения ею двух массивов, второй из которых будет содержать массивы для проверки, или ввести ещё один обязательный аргумент, содержащий указание глубины погружения, но я не уверен, что это -- оптимальный вариант.

Поэтому вопрос: Нет ли способа передать все элементы массива в функцию, в качестве независимых аргументов? Есть функция `list()`, но она просто превратит массив из десяти элементов в десять отдельных переменных, которые всё равно придётся передавать функции вручную, как и если бы я просто перечислил все элементы массива. Хотелось бы что-то более элегантное, тем более, что я почти уверен, что такое решение есть, просто я его не нашёл.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы передать в функцию массив, как список аргументов, нужно поставить перед ним три точки, вот так:

```
myFunc(...[$arg1, $arg2]);
```

Работает на php v5.6 и выше.

Answer (score 8):

Используйте функцию [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
call_user_func_array($callable, array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));
```